# How to append to a nested list inside a list of dictionaries?

Tags: python-3.8

I am aware that this question has already been answered in the past but I am not able to generalize solutions to my problem, probably because I don't quite understand the underlying reason for this behaviour.

I have the following list:

```
matches = [
{'name': 'gm1', 'odds': {'full time': {'3way': []}}},
{'name': 'gm2', 'odds': {'full time': {'3way': []}}},
{'name': 'gm2', 'odds': {'full time': {'3way': []}}},
]
```

When I run:

```
for match in matches:
    match['odds']['full time']['3way'].append({'match_index': matches.index(match)})
```

I expect to get:

```
[{'name': 'gm1', 'odds': {'full time': {'3way': [{'match_index': 0}]}}},
{'name': 'gm2', 'odds': {'full time': {'3way': [{'match_index': 1}]}}},
{'name': 'gm2', 'odds': {'full time': {'3way': [{'match_index': 2}]}}}]
```

and I am getting:

```
[{'name': 'gm1', 'odds': {'full time': {'3way': [{'match_index': 0}, {'match_index': 1}, {'match_index': 2}]}}},
{'name': 'gm2', 'odds': {'full time': {'3way': [{'match_index': 0}, {'match_index': 1}, {'match_index': 2}]}}},
{'name': 'gm2', 'odds': {'full time': {'3way': [{'match_index': 0}, {'match_index': 1}, {'match_index': 2}]}}}]
```

To add to the confusion this works as expected if I manually generate the list in my IDE but it produces unwanted results when the same list is loaded from a file.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is the issue, but you did not add commas to separate the elements in the matches list:

```
matches=[{'name': 'gm1', 'odds': {'full time': {'3way': []}}},{'name': 'gm2', 'odds': {'full time': {'3way': []}}},{'name': 'gm3', 'odds': {'full time': {'3way': []}}}]
```

After I have run you for I got correct result:

```
>>> for match in matches:
...     match['odds']['full time']['3way'].append({'index': matches.index(match)})
```

Output:

```
>>> matches
[{'name': 'gm1', 'odds': {'full time': {'3way': [{'index': 0}]}}}, {'name': 'gm2', 'odds': {'full time': {'3way': [{'index': 1}]}}}, {'name': 'gm3', 'odds': {'full time': {'3way': [{'index': 2}]}}}]
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I omitted the commas by accident, the original code is fine. It works for me either unless I load the list from a pickle file which containts scraped data from a website. The manually created and a loaded list are definitely the same but the resulting lists produced by appending to them are for some reason different.